# Passing variable in a URL (php) & file_get_contents()

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

Is there a way to pass a variable in a URL with file_get_contents() and have file_get_contents() retrieve dynamic content that is based on the value of the variable passed?

For example, let's say I have the following code on a page on **Website A**:

```
$contents=file_get_contents('http://example.com/get.php?a='.$number);
echo $contents;
```

where `$number` is generated on Website A (values can be 1, 2, 3, etc.)

Then on **example.com**, `get.php` is hosted. Is it possible to retrieve different content from `get.php` based on the value of the variable passed? For example, if `a=1` then a certain part of `get.php` would be fetched, but if `a=2` and different part of `get.php` would be fetched, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: If only there was a way to test this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Certainly.

It is possible if you figure out the pattern for the variables.

If you notice that the pattern is a number you might try something like this:

You don't want to show anything that's not going to be pertinent in the code or output and you don't want to get into filtering on the fly because it will only add delay. In `get.php` on the target machine:

```
if(!empty($_GET['a']) and is_numeric($_GET['a'])){

$id = $_GET['a'];
$sql = "select contents from database where id='$id'";
$results = mysqli_query($sql);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row_cnt == 1){

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo $row['contents'];
   }
} elseif (empty($row_cnt) {
  echo "No results";
} else {
  echo "Too many records.";
}

} else {
 die;
}
```

In the machine doing the mining (machine 2):

```
$contents = '';

for($x=0;$x<150;$x++){
  $contents.=file_get_contents('http://example.com/get.php?a='.$number);
}

echo $contents;
```

Remember when opening a URL over the web that you need to:

1. grant [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) access if necessary
2. add a delay so you're not overwhelming the target server's resources
3. verify that you're not in violation of someone's [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file
4. pass proper headers including user_agent so your server is not banned
5. increase the run time limits if you're running the script as a webpage under Apache.

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is much more appropriate for this and contains many advanced features.

### Update - but it's probably not a good idea

The above example would be for just one or two pages, not for viewing the contents on a website as re-showing the contents. I misunderstood and thought you were datamining a site (one-time).

**LAN**
On a local network LAN showing the contents from one server on another should be pretty fast and the websites should perform fairly quickly (by modern standards) even though you're mining content.

You'll want to add the target site's domain and ip to the hosts file so the system doesn't perform a DNS look-up (if caching is disabled) everytime the function is called.

**Same box**
If they were on the same machine you might overload the system if some sort of pauses aren't in place.

**WAN**
If you're on two separate networks in two server farms separated by some distance the number of hops will greatly impact the performance of the script. This is not a good idea in terms of running a live production server for any length of time. Most people will not wait a couple of seconds for a page to load.

Additionally you'll want to filter the mining server's ip out of the stats for the server being mined as it will look like all of your traffic on the target computer comes from one location.

Since they are on two different boxes you'll want to make sure something like IP tables (the firewall) won't lock all access on the target server because you might connect repeatedly to the site too quickly from the same IP. If you're not in control of both networks all sorts of things can also block repeated access such as firewalls and routers. Many web hosts do not like repeated high volumes of traffic. Also you may be penalized for bandwidth if you accidentally misconfigure either box.

**Database Replication**
If you're pulling contents from a database you may want to look into database replication and keep two copies of the database on each machine. Then you would simply load the contents as you would any other file.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. I control both websites/scripts. So let's say on `http://wwww.domain1.com/example.php` I have the code `$contents=file_get_contents('http://example.com/get.php?a='.$number);
echo $contents;` and `$number=something` , and then in the file `http://example.com/get.php` there are various contents that correspond to each possible variable (a=1 , a=2, etc) and I want to only fetch the content that corresponds to the variable and then post it in `http://wwww.domain1.com/example.php`. Is this possible and how can it be done? How could it be done in cURL?

Comment: @Davidmichael are they both on the same box?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm still unsure how to implement this; what would I have to put in `get.php`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Davidmichael I've updated my response to show some example code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends only on `get.php`. If it returns different content on different values of `a`, it sure will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding you correctly. Your script:

```
http://wwww.domain1.com/get.php
```

Some other resource:

```
http://www.resource.com/other.php
```

Your get.php, could look like this:

```
$findResource = $_GET['a'];
// You should perform some validation here on the $findResource value to prevent security issues
$contents=file_get_contents('http://www.resource.com/other.php?a='.$findResource);
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. I control both websites/scripts. So let's say on `http://wwww.domain1.com/example.php` I have the code `$contents=file_get_contents('http://example.com/get.php?a='.$number);
echo $contents;` and `$number=something` , and then in the file `http://example.com/get.php` there are various contents that correspond to each possible variable (a=1 , a=2, etc) and I want to only fetch the content that corresponds to the variable and then post it in `http://wwww.domain1.com/example.php`. Is this possible and how can it be done?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible, but you have to concern about privacy policy (scraping is not allowed on many sites).