# Making a template with vars and file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php

I have a php page that is reading from a file:

```
$name = "World";
$file = file_get_contents('html.txt', true);
$file = file_get_contents('html.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

echo $file;
```

In the html.txt I have the following:

```
Hello $name!
```

When I go to the site, I get "Hello $name!" and not Hello World!

Is there a way to get var's in the txt file to output their value and not their name?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Use include instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: Think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905706/php-sending-variables-to-file-get-contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second param of [**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) has nothing to do with how to interpret the file - it's about which pathes to check when looking for that file.

The result, however, will always be a *complete* string, and you can only "reinterpolate" it with [ev<del>i</del>al](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

What might be a better idea is using the combination of [**include**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [**output control functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

**Main file:**

```
<?php

$name = "World";
ob_start();
include('html.tpl');
$file = ob_get_clean();
echo $file;
```

**html.tpl:**

```
Hello <?= $name ?>
```

Note that php tags (`<?= ... ?>`) in the text (`'.tpl'`) file - without it `$name` will not be parsed as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach with predefined values (instead of all variables in scope):

```
    $name = "World";
    $name2 = "John";

    $template = file_get_contents ('html_templates/template.html');

    $replace_array = array(
        ':name' => $name,
        ':name2' => $name2,
        ...
    );

    $final_html = strtr($template, $replace_array);
```

And in the template.html you would have something like this:

```
    <div>Hello :name!</div>
    <div>And also hi to you, :name2!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question, you'll need to use the 'eval' function in php.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

But from a development perspective, I would consider if there was a better way to do that, either by storing $name somewhere more accessible or by re-evaluating your process.  Using things like the eval function can introduce some serious security risks.