# Echo php variable inside file retrieved from get_file_contents

Tags: php

I am trying to get the variables echoed inside a template file used for the unique `div` id's, but it keeps outputting the entire string and ignoring the php tags. My code and results are below:

comment.php:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);

$idOfContent = 1;
$numberOfComments = 4;

while($idOfContent<=$numberOfComments){
    $content = file_get_contents('comment_tmpl.php');
    echo $content;
    $idOfContent +=1;
}


?>
```

comment_tmpl.php:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Content" id="<? echo $idOfContent ?>">
        <div class="PhotoContainer"> Image here </div>
        <div class="CommentAndReplyContainer">
            <div class="CommentBox" id="TopCommentBox_<? echo $idOfContent ?>">
                <form method="post" action="comment.php">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="<? echo $idOfContent ?>_comment" onclick="this.value='';" > Write a comment </textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" name="buttonId" value="<? echo $idOfContent ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Post" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

results:

`<div class="Content" id="<?php echo $idOfContent ?>"></div>`

How do I get it to recognize the PHP tags and output the variables correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sending variables to file\_get\_contents()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905706/php-sending-variables-to-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `file_get_contents()` function will, as the name says, fetch the contents inside `comment_tpl.php` and the echo will output it in the HTML markup, but it won't be correctly parsed as PHP code.  I'm not sure why you're doing this, but you're probably looking for [`include()`](http://php.net/include):

```
while($idOfContent<=$numberOfComments){
    include('comment_tmpl.php');
    $idOfContent +=1;
}
```

Alternatively, you could  use [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval), but it's a very bad idea and I don't recommend it.

Comment: `include()` and `eval()` are the same thing in PHP, just use different sources.

Comment: Your correct I guess I didn't realize that I could include the file like that multiple times I'm still kind of a squid at PHP haha

Comment: @mario: but `include()` is still a lot better, no?

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, yes it is. Not because of microoptimizations, but because it fits the task exactly.