# Put a php string into a html file while echo with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, html, string, put

im looking for a way to put a php string into a html file, which i pull into with file_get_contents and echo then.

PHP Snipped:

```
if($_GET['title'] == "main"){
    $name = "Jan";
    $page = file_get_contents('pages/main.html');
    echo $page;
}
```

HTML Snipped:

```
<div id='personal_data'>
    Persönliche Daten:</br>
    Name: $name</br>
    Alter: 18</br>
    Wohnort: Keine Ahnung
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are similar questions on here: eg. [PHP sending variables to file_get_contents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905706/php-sending-variables-to-file-get-contents)
But file_get_contents is just returning a string, so str_replace should work on it.

```
# https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
$bodytag = str_replace("%body%", "black", "<body text='%body%'>");

# your example
if($_GET['title'] == "main"){
    $name = "Jan";
    $page = file_get_contents('pages/main.html');
    echo str_replace('$name', $name, $page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `file_get_contents()` you're processing your HTML file like plain text file, PHP will not parse it or interpret anything from it. The `echo` will then print the raw content of this file.

If you're new to PHP & you're trying to load a page and interpret variables, I suggest you to take a look a some PHP introduction topics & tutorials on the web at first. Unless you're building a kind of page-caching, this will not be easy and practicle for you to maintain.

By the way, if you want to "include" HTML content from a file into your main PHP file, you have to use `include()` or `require()` functions.

Here is some example of file inclusion : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_inclusion.htm