# How to pass data to pdf in just DOMPDF?

Tags: php, dompdf

I am stuck in a weird situation.
How can I send PHP data to dompdf's pdf ?

Here is my code 
**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';  
use Dompdf\Dompdf; 
use Dompdf\Options;

function runPDF () {
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    $data = array('name'=>'John Smith', 'date'=>'1/29/15');

    $html = file_get_contents("pdf.php"); 
    $dompdf->loadHTML($html); 
    
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); 
    $dompdf->render(); 
    $dompdf->stream("niceshipest", array("Attachment" => 0));

}

if (isset($_GET['pdf'])) {
    runPDF();
  }
?>

<a href='?pdf=true' target="_blank">print</a>
```

**pdf.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Value To PDF</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Hello <?php echo $data['name']; ?>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So how can I access that $data value in generated pdf?

I have tried to change isPhpEnabled = false;  to isPhpEnabled = true;

But got no results.

Framworke version of dompdf like laravel-dompdf provides feature to pass data in HTML like loadView();  but there is only loadHTML();

Any help really appreciate?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905706/php-sending-variables-to-file-get-contents

Answer (score 0):

The solution it's very simple, you should just add the `with()` like this :

```
$dompdf->loadHTML($html)->with('data', $data);
```

And you should delete this :

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
```

That's it.